# Android - Asking permission to see user location

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-permissions, android-location

I am trying to ask the user permission to access their location. This is my MainActivity but permission is not being asked when I run the app. I have entered the code for permissions at the end of the activity. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.example.googlemapsadding;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
{

private GoogleMap mMap;
private final String LOG_TAG = "LaurenceTestApp";
private TextView txtOutput;
private TextView latitude;
private TextView longitude;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Marker curPosMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    txtOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutput);
    latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;

    /* Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(10,19);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    */
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
{
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create(); // Another way to write a new object
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(2 * 1000); // Always write in milliseconds

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, location.toString());

    double tempLat = location.getLatitude();
    double tempLong = location.getLongitude();

     // Make a marker
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(tempLat,tempLong);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
    /*
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions(); // MarkerOptions object to hold marker attributes
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    curPosMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions); // Add marker with markerOptions options
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

    if (curPosMarker != null) // Keep only one marker for an object and delete past ones
    {
        mMap.clear();
    }

    curPosMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
    */
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                    //    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    //}
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think you should not call the permission in onConnected().Try it to use in onCreate().

Comment: @AndroidGeek It is not working still.

Comment: check the target version in your `build.gradle` file, it should be 23 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I completely erased my permission code and followed this tutorial from scratch - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2JaVke71RY. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should request GRANTED with ALL LOCATION PERMISSION

```
    String mPerms[] = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    ...
    if (checkSelfPermission(mPerms[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
        || checkSelfPermission(mPerms[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        requestPermissions(mPerms, CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
    } else {
        // TODO Location checker
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(resultCallback);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on what you mean?

Comment: I saw your code, you request permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION without ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

Comment: Sorry. I just tried that and still not getting the permission box.

Comment: Sorry, what os version you tested ? ?
This request permission feature is only adapt for OS.Build.VERSION_CODES.M later

Comment: I am testing on my phone which has API lvl 23.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Utilities](https://github.com/abhishek-tm/google-utilities) library to get location easily with permission..

```
locationHandler = new LocationHandler(this)
    .setLocationListener(new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Get the best known location
    }
}).start();
```

For more details about location handler, read out [wiki](https://github.com/abhishek-tm/google-utilities/wiki/Location-Handler)...

Answer (score 0):

check the target version in your `build.gradle` file, it should be 23 or higher.

Comment: The target version is set as 25. Should I change it to 23?